# Folding/unfolding considered an undo/redo "step"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Seems like in visual studio folding/unfolding a section is considered an undo "step".

That is if I fold a section then press undo it will unfold it. The same goes for redo.

To me this is highly confusing, folding/unfolding is navigation and should not be considered for undo/redo.

Is there a way to change this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the [Disable Outlining Undo](https://vlasovstudio.com/disable-outlining-undo/) extension that prevents it.